# ggplot2's geom_text refusing to dodge

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a pretty straightforward dataset consisting of a week of two totals in groups, which I'm displaying in an identity bar plot using ggplot2 (version 3.3.0).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(lubridate)
weeksummary <- data.frame(
    Date = rep(as.POSIXct("2020-01-01") + days(0:6), 2),
    Total = rpois(14, 30),
    Group = c(rep("group1", 7), rep("group2", 7))
)

ggplot(data = weeksummary, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = Total, fill = Group)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_text(aes(label = Total), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 3)
```

[image: NotWorking]

I cannot for the life of me get this to put the numbers at the top of their own bars, been hunting around for an answer and trying everything I found with no luck, until I randomly tried this:

```
weeksummary$Date <- as.factor(weeksummary$Date)
```

[image: Working]

But this seems unnecessary manipulation, and I'd need to make sure the dates appear in the right format and order and rewrite the additional bits that currently rely on dates... I'd rather understand what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is to use `as.Date.POSIXct`.  `as.factor()` works to force `weeksummary$Date` into a factor, but it forces the conversion of your POSIXct class into a character first (thus erasing "date").  However, you need to convert to a factor so that dodging works properly - that's the question.

You can either convert before (e.g. `weeksummary$Date <- as.Date.POXIXct(weeksummary$Date)`), or do it right in your plot call:

```
ggplot(weeksummary, aes(x = as.Date.POSIXct(Date), y = Total, fill = Group)) +
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
    geom_text(aes(label = Total, y = Total + 1),
        position = position_dodge(width = 0.9), size = 3)
```

Giving you this:

*Note: the values are different than your values, since our randomization seeds are likely not the same :)*

[image]

You'll notice I nudged the labels up a bit.  You can normally do this with `nudge_y`, but you cannot specify `nudge_x` or `nudge_y` the same time you specify a `position=` argument.  In this case, you can just nudge by overwriting the y aesthetic.

Comment: Right, so to extrapolate my answer from what you've given, is that `as.POSIXct` is too granular a scale to assume factor-like values on, so they're ignored by dodge (strangely enough, only in `geom_text`). Using the Date class instead does indeed just work, which is easy enough to just set in the first place (as it is already a manipulation from a much larger dataset - was actually just calling Lubridate's floor_date).

Comment: Yes, that sounds right - more like that POSIXct is actually a "special" numeric - so it's continuous data (from what I understand, basically it's # of days or # of milliseconds past a "zero" date).  "Dates" as we know them operate more like discrete data - `ggplot` can't dodge numeric/continuous data, but only discrete data.  Like - if you tried this with numeric x and numeric y data and tried to dodge, it wouldn't work either.  I don't know if it would throw an error, but would not actually "dodge" the data for you.

Comment: Discrete, that was the term I was looking for, geom_text requires discrete values to dodge on. A bit senseless in this case, as it's actually dodging on the grouping, not the values, but at least it's an answer lol. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Because `geom_text` inherits x aesthetics which is `Date` in this case, which is totally correct. You don't have to mutate your data frame, you can specify the behaviour when plotting instead

`aes(x = factor(Date), y = ...)`,

Comment: If I put `x = as.factor(Date)` in the aes call in geom_text() I get an error that time_trans works with POSIXct only. So I'd have to put that in the ggplot() call meaning it's not much different to mutating the original data frame. Additionally, as.character() works just as well, so is it just that geom_text has an issue with scalar values?